# Ignore or remove lines from data connection

Tags: excel, vba

I pull some data in from a text file. Same format every day, but different data

This populates into a live report for my team to view and monitor.

The last column in the report is "allowed". Currently, I just delete any row with "allowed" in

What I want to be able to do is either remove it before the data populates, or delete the rows straight after the import

Note, the option for "allowed" are "YES" and blank

Is it possible to stop a line being entered when in data entry?

My code is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Import()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRowC As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
lastRowC = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' bottom populated cell of Column "C", plus 1

    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;N:\Operations\001 Daily Management\Shop Goods\FMSQRY.CSV", Destination:= _
            ws.Cells(lastRowC, 2))
        .Name = "FMSQRY"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Connections("FMSQRY").Delete
        With ws
            .Names("FMSQRY").Delete
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub TodaysDate()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRowC As Long, lastRowH As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Report")

lastRowH = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' bottom populated cell of Column "A", plus 1
lastRowC = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' bottom populated cell of Column "B"

    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastRowH, 1), ws.Cells(lastRowC, 1))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Something similar is done here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27892219/Filter-data-from-text-file-before-import-to-Excel.html

Comment: Does your data contain appropriate headers?

Comment: Also see: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/63364-filter-text-file-while-importing

Comment: Hi, my data has no headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could manage to have appropiate headers you could filter using an ADO connection and an SQL statement. But since you have no appropiate headers in your CSV data, the easiest solution would be to delete the rows right after import.

Imagine the following data after import:

[image]

The following code will delete all rows containing `allowed` in column F. You need to adjust the column name to the column name you used:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestDeleteAllAllowed()
    lastRowC = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' bottom populated cell of Column "C", plus 1

    'your import stuff here        

    DeleteAllAllowed StartRow:=lastRowC 
End Sub


Public Sub DeleteAllAllowed(Optional StartRow As Long = 1)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report") 'define worksheet

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column F

    If LastRow < StartRow Then Exit Sub

    Dim DataArray As Variant 'read column F into array
    DataArray = ws.Columns("F").Resize(RowSize:=LastRow - StartRow + 1).Offset(RowOffset:=StartRow - 1).Value 'column F contains "allowed"

    Dim RowsToDelete As Range 'we collect all rows to delete here

    If IsArray(DataArray) Then
        Dim iRow As Long
        For iRow = 1 To LastRow - StartRow + 1
            If DataArray(iRow, 1) = "allowed" Then
                If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                    Set RowsToDelete = ws.Rows(iRow + StartRow - 1)
                Else
                    Set RowsToDelete = Union(RowsToDelete, ws.Rows(iRow + StartRow - 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next iRow
    Else
        If DataArray = "allowed" Then
            Set RowsToDelete = ws.Rows(LastRow)
        End If
    End If

    If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        RowsToDelete.Delete 'delete all rows at once
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So ref this, I can see that the headers can be an issue. I should say the `.csv` files that I import have no headers, but the spreadsheet does. As the `.csv` append to the spreadsheet every time I get a new file. Secondly, would any time be saved if I used today's date to start the deletion of the rows, as "yesterday's" data will not have "allowed" in Column F as it would already be cleared

Comment: For using an SQL statement the CSV itself needs to have the header to make it work. I didn't get the point of your second question. Can you please be more precise?

Comment: Given running your script above, all data would no longer have rows with "allowed" in. Tomorrow I would be importing another file (and the next day etc). Would any processing time be saved by using the date of the report (pulled in from a separate module) as the starting point. i.e 20/05/19 would have no "allowed". 21/05/19 would have allowed but the script would run from 01/05/19 onwards, every time. That means in December, this would be looking at files rows that have not had "allowed" against them in 7 months. Thanks

Comment: @Badja you could introduce a `StartRow` parameter that you can set to `DeleteAllAllowed StartRow:=lastRowC` which you used as beginning. So it would only loop through the new data (see selection) and omit the old one.

Comment: I'm getting an error 13 mismatch on `DataArray = ws.Columns("M").Resize(RowSize:=LastRow - StartRow + 1).Offset(RowOffset:=StartRow - 1).Value`

Comment: With exactly my code? I tested it it works. What are the values of `LastRow` and `StartRow` in case of error?

Comment: They are both 35 for me. All I've changed is "F" to "M" and added my date import inbetween `'your import stuff here` and `DeleteAllAllowed StartRow:=lastRowC`

Comment: If you look at my `TodaysDate` sub - because it is now part of the Import, `lastRowC`'s value is changed to 35 before the Delete sub. I've changed it to `lastRowH` and that works, but I'm now getting error 9

Comment: @Badja my bad, it failed if there was only one data cell to check. fixed it.

Comment: `For iRow = 1 To LastRow` now loops 8 times fine, on 9 it gives me Error 9 subscript out of range

Comment: @Badja please copy the whole function I changed more than you might have seen. It is `For iRow = 1 To LastRow - StartRow + 1`.

Comment: Hi, this works now. Although it's deleting everything except "allowed" - can you switch this?

Comment: Ahh damn it. I fixed it again the countings were wrong. Sorry :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193712/discussion-between-badja-and-p).

Answer (score 1):

**Requirements:**
   Import a CSV file on a daily basis
   The CSV file does not have headers
   Exclude all records marked as `YES` in the field number 12 of the CSV file
   Values in the field 12 are: `YES` and `Null` (i.e. blank)
   Append the filtered CSV data into an existing worksheet named `Report`
   The new data should be posted at the end of the existing data, starting at column 2
   In column 1 the new data shall have the date when the data was imported.

**Solution:**
This solution uses `ADODB.Connection`, `ADODB.RecordSet` and a `SQL` statement to filter the data and add the `Date` field (at the first position) containing the processing date.
Yes, we all have heard many times about the myth, that an ADODB connection requires headers… Not really!
Let’s use the following `Connection` properties:

```
.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & sPath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties='text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited(,)'"`
```

where:
`sPath` : contains the file location
`HDR=No` : indicates there is no header
`FMT=Delimited(,)` : indicates a csv file

This `SQL command` extracts the required data, while adding the field `Date` :

```
"SELECT #" & Date & "# As [DATE], * FROM [" & sFile & "] Where [F12] Is Null"
```

This function creates a `recordset` with the data extracted from the CSV file as per the `SQL statement` provided.
It has the `recordset` (output object), the `path`, `filename` and `SQL statement` as parameters to provide flexibility.
It returns a boolean indicating the result of the process. `True` : record(s) matching the `SQL command` were found and extracted, `False` : no records matched the `SQL command`.

```
Public Function SQL_ƒCsv_ToRecordSet(oOutput As Object, _
    sPath As String, sFile As String, sSql As String) As Boolean
Dim oAdCn As Object, oAdRs As Object

    Rem Set Objects
    Set oAdCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set oAdRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Rem Open Connection
    With oAdCn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & sPath & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties='text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited(,)'"
        .Open
    End With

    Rem Apply SQL to Source
    With oAdRs
        .LockType = 1                   'adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = 3                 'adOpenStatic
        .ActiveConnection = oAdCn
        .Open Source:=sSql, Options:=1  'adCmdText
        Rem Validate Results
        If .RecordCount = 0 Then Exit Function
    End With

    Rem Set Results
    Set oOutput = oAdRs
    SQL_ƒCsv_ToRecordSet = True

    End Function
```

Use this the procedure to call the function:

```
Private Sub Csv_Import()
Dim oAdRs As Object, ws As Worksheet
Dim sPath As String, sFile As String, sSql As String
Dim lRow As Long, sMsgBdy As String

    Rem Set Variables & Objects
    sFile = "FMSQRY.CSV"
    sPath = "N:\Operations\001 Daily Management\Shop Goods"     'No separator at the end!
    sSql = "SELECT #" & Date & "# As [DATE], * FROM [" & sFile & "] Where [F12] Is Null"    'Update as required
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")      'Update as required

    Rem Extract filtered data from csv file
    If SQL_ƒCsv_ToRecordSet(oAdRs, sPath, sFile, sSql) Then

        Rem Post extracted records (with the date of extraction in Field 1)
        With ws
            lRow = 1 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(lRow, 1).CopyFromRecordset oAdRs
        End With
        sMsgBdy = "Records added successfully…"

    Else
        Rem No Records Filtered
        sMsgBdy = "No records found in: " & vbCrLf _
            & vbTab & sFile & vbCrLf _
            & vbTab & sPath

    End If
    MsgBox sMsgBdy, vbInformation

    End Sub
```